# Schur symmetric functions

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

Let $s_{\lambda}$ denotes the Schur function associated to a partition $\lambda$ of $n$. Let $\lambda = (3,2)$, then by Giambelli's formula $s_{(3,2)} =det\begin{pmatrix}
s_{3} & s_{4} \\
s_1 & s_2
\end{pmatrix}$. The conjugate partition of $(3,2)$ is $(2,2,1)$. So $s_{(2,2,1)}$ can be written as $s_{(2,2,1)}=det\begin{pmatrix}
s_{(1,1,1)} & s_{(1,1,1,1)} \\
s_1 & s_{1,1}
\end{pmatrix}$. Now the question is can $s_{(3,2)}+s_{(2,2,1)}$ be written in some nice form (determinant or pfaffian or resultant or some other) in terms of $s_{\mu}+s_{\mu'}$ where $\mu'$ is the conjugate partition.

Comment: Here you have $s_{(3, 2)} + s_{(2, 2, 1)} = s_{(2, 2)} s_{(1)}$, and the elements on the right hand side are self-conjugate. Is there any particular reason you're after this sort of decomposition?

Comment: Thanks but I am expecting in terms of one row partitions. Recently I came across with this result (without proof) is that $s_{\lambda}+s_{\lambda'}$ can be written in terms of $s_{\mu}+s_{\mu'}$ where $\mu$ is a one row partition. Just I am wondering if there is a nice formula like Giambelli for this.